# how to get selected value in Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to print the selected value, and below is my option list:

```
const vesselName = [
  {
    value: '0',
    label: 'ALBIDDA',
  },
  {
    value: '1',
    label: 'ALRUMEILA',
  },
  {
    value: '2',
    label: 'MAJD',
  },
  {
    value: '3',
    label: 'OSHAIRIJ',
  },
]
```

here is the structure of my select components:

```
const App = () => {const [status, setStatus] = useState([0])const [vessel, setVessel] = useState('')const handleSelect = (value, evt) => {setVessel(evt.label)console.log(vessel)}
```

```
return (<div style={{ margin: '50px' }}><Row gutter={[50, 50]}><Col><Row><div style={{ padding: '8px 10px 0 0' }}>Vessel Name:</div><SelectdefaultValue="0"options={vesselName}style={{ width: '120px' }}onChange={(value, evt) => handleSelect(value, evt)}value={vessel}/></Row></Col>
```

now the problem is every time, I click the option, the previous selection value will be printed out, why this happened?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isJaZ.png)

when I clicked the third option, the second option will be printed out.

and what default value should I set in useState? Because I have set the default value in <select/>, but when I use useState, the default value did not work.

Comment: setting a state value is an async operation, so immediately calling `console.log(stateValue)` will probably result in previous value. so you should `console.log` out of `handleSelect` and it should log it every time the component renders.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is my example. I hope that can help you. the default should be the value of an obj of the array that you wanted as a default selected object.

[pls check it out here: example of select react & antD](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-leftpad-1sjuz3)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Select } from "antd";
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [obj, setObj] = useState();

  const vesselName = [
    {
      value: "0",
      label: "ALBIDDA"
    },
    {
      value: "1",
      label: "ALRUMEILA"
    },
    {
      value: "2",
      label: "MAJD"
    },
    {
      value: "3",
      label: "OSHAIRIJ"
    }
  ];
  const handleChange = (value, option) => {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(option);
    console.log(option.label);
    setValue(value);
    setObj(option);
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "50px" }}>
      <Row gutter={[50, 50]}>
        <Col>
          <Row>
            <div style={{ padding: "8px 10px 0 0" }}>Vessel Name:</div>
            <Select
              defaultValue={value}
              style={{ width: 120 }}
              onChange={handleChange}
              options={vesselName}
            />
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <div>
              <p>selected obj: {JSON.stringify(obj)}</p>
              <p>Selected Value: {JSON.stringify(value)}</p>
            </div>
          </Row>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```